# Unload Outlook item from memory

Tags: vba, outlook

From this section of the documentation: AppointmentItem.Unload event (Outlook) [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.unload]

There is the description: Occurs before an Outlook item is unloaded from memory, either programmatically or by user action.

I'm not able to found how to do it programmatically. Can you send me how to do it or update docs?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This is an event, not a method, of the `AppointmentItem`.

Comment: @BigBen true, but I want to remove AppointmentItem from memory. And I'm not able to found how to do it...

Comment: `Set objectVariableName = Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what MSDN states for the `Unload` event:

> This event occurs after the Close event for the Outlook item occurs, but before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, allowing an add-in to release any resources related to the object. Although the event occurs before the Outlook item is unloaded from memory, this event cannot be canceled.

So, you need to close an inspector window or, if it is selected in the Explorer view, change the selection by moving it to another item and releasing the pointer. In VBA you need to set the object to `Nothing` for that.